# Can the content of a email read receipt be set in the original email?

Tags: c#, smtpclient

I use the following code to send a message and require a read receipt. Then I use outlook to open this message and send back the read receipt. The read receipt is received, my question is could I set the content of the read receipt in the original message?

```
   MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
   message.From = new MailAddress("abc@abc.com");
   message.To.Add("123@123.com");
   message.Subject = "test";
   message.Headers.Add("Disposition-Notification-To", "<def@abc.com>");

   SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.abc.com");
   client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("abc@abc.com", "password");
   client.Send(message);
```

Comment: I do not see any headers that refer to receipt text or the like.  IF you are able to set the text of the receipt in outlook, then you should be able to view the headers of the message and see where it is setting that so you can do the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I have bad news for you. You can't set the delivery receipt text on the "sender-side", there is no such possibility in the SMTP protocol. So it's generated by the recipient.